# Can Azure ExpressRoute be connected to multiple subscriptions that are owned by different organizations?

Tags: azure, subscription, vendor

I have an ExpressRoute circuit and gateway associated with my Enteprise Organizations Azure subscription.  Can I connect to multiple other Azure subscriptions that are not owned by my company - ie.  managed cloud solutions running in Azure from other vendors?  If so, what are the data usage chargeback implications of doing so?